# Ruby, Rails, Assign specific arbitrary letter to years

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Assuming 2021 = 'M' and 2022 = 'N', and when we reach the 'Z' the following year will be 'A'.  How should I match X year with the correct letter code?

Comment: What should happen once the alpha pattern repeats?  In other words, what should the year 2047 be?  Should it be “M”?  Or should the alpha value always be unique?

Comment: Breaking down a VIN? Although that would contain digits 1-9 and exclude certain letters (I, O, Q) so it may just be happenstantial that you placed letters corresponding to vehicle years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mod operator and ASCII codes...

```
(2021..2080).each do |yr|
  puts "#{yr}: #{(((yr + 19)  % 26) + 65).chr}"
end
```

Or more explicitly...

```
ASCII_CODE_A = 65.freeze

(2021..2080).each do |yr|
  offset = (yr + 19) % 26 
  year_ascii_code = offset + ASCII_CODE_A
  year_letter_code = year_ascii_code.chr
  puts "#{yr}: #{year_letter_code}"
end
```

The [`chr`](https://apidock.com/ruby/v2_5_5/Integer/chr) method outputs the character of the supplied integer.

Output...

```
2021: M
2022: N
2023: O
2024: P
2025: Q
2026: R
2027: S
2028: T
2029: U
2030: V
2031: W
2032: X
2033: Y
2034: Z
2035: A
2036: B
2037: C
2038: D
2039: E
2040: F
2041: G
2042: H
2043: I
2044: J
2045: K
2046: L
2047: M
2048: N
2049: O
2050: P
2051: Q
2052: R
2053: S
2054: T
2055: U
2056: V
2057: W
2058: X
2059: Y
2060: Z
2061: A
2062: B
2063: C
2064: D
2065: E
2066: F
2067: G
2068: H
2069: I
2070: J
2071: K
2072: L
2073: M
2074: N
2075: O
2076: P
2077: Q
2078: R
2079: S
2080: T
```

Comment: +1 for using the character to determine the year. Although the `freeze` is superfluous since Integers are immutable.

Comment: Force of habit. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
LTRS = [*'M'..'Z', *'A'..'L']
  #=> ["M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y",
  #    "Z", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L"]
```

```
def doit(yr)
  LTRS[(yr - 2021) % 26]
end
```

Try it.

```
(2021..2070).each do |yr|
  print "#{yr} -> #{doit(yr)}   "
  puts if ((yr - 2020) % 6).zero?
end
2021 -> M   2022 -> N   2023 -> O   2024 -> P   2025 -> Q   2026 -> R   
2027 -> S   2028 -> T   2029 -> U   2030 -> V   2031 -> W   2032 -> X   
2033 -> Y   2034 -> Z   2035 -> A   2036 -> B   2037 -> C   2038 -> D   
2039 -> E   2040 -> F   2041 -> G   2042 -> H   2043 -> I   2044 -> J   
2045 -> K   2046 -> L   2047 -> M   2048 -> N   2049 -> O   2050 -> P   
2051 -> Q   2052 -> R   2053 -> S   2054 -> T   2055 -> U   2056 -> V   
2057 -> W   2058 -> X   2059 -> Y   2060 -> Z   2061 -> A   2062 -> B   
2063 -> C   2064 -> D   2065 -> E   2066 -> F   2067 -> G   2068 -> H   
2069 -> I   2070 -> J
```